# Empty return value when parsing JSON using XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, json, typescript

I have been trying to parse a bit of JSON from an API now and it was all working when I used

```
xmlHttp.open('GET', url, false);
```

But when I later wanted to expand my code using timeouts for the requests my function started to return empty values.

This is the function doing the actual parsing:

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
          if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
              obj = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
              console.log(obj);
           }
      }
  };
```

When I log the object returned here using console.log I get the JSON printed out to the console normally but later in my function I am returning the obj variable but it is always empty.

Here is the whole function:

```
static Parse(url: string): Object{
  Asserts.isUrl(url, 'URL is invalid');
  var obj = new Object();
  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
          if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
              obj = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
              //console.log(obj);
           }
      }
  };

  xmlHttp.open('GET', url, true);
  xmlHttp.timeout = 2000;
  xmlHttp.ontimeout = function () {
    xmlHttp.abort();
    throw new Error("Request Timed Out.");
  };
  xmlHttp.send();

  return obj;
}
```

My first thought that it had something to do with the scope in Javascript but now after being stuck here for a few hours without progress I am clueless.

As I mentioned inside the xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () the console.log is actually logging the correct value. It's just that the obj variable created at the start of the function is not getting the value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

AJAX is asynchronous. This means that the `onreadystatechange` function will be called at a much later stage, probably after you have already returned from the `Parse` method. So you should not be trying to return `obj` from the `Parse` method. You would rather have the `Parse` method take an additional parameter that represents a callback function which you will invoke inside the `onreadystatechange` event and pass it the resulting object.

Here's what I mean:

```
static Parse(url: string, done: (obj: any) => void): void {
    Asserts.isUrl(url, 'URL is invalid');
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
                var obj = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
                // Pass the resulting object to the callback function
                done(obj);
            }
        }
    };

    xmlHttp.open('GET', url, true);
    xmlHttp.timeout = 2000;
    xmlHttp.ontimeout = function () {
        xmlHttp.abort();
        throw new Error("Request Timed Out.");
    };
    xmlHttp.send();
}
```

and here's how you would call the `Parse` function:

```
Parse('http://foobar', function(obj) => {
    // TODO: do something with obj here
    console.log(obj);
});
```

So basically when you are writing a javascript application that uses asynchronous AJAX calls you should stop thinking in terms of sequential functions that you will invoke one after the other and which will return values. You should start thinking in terms of callbacks.

Comment: How would i make the function wait for the onreadystatechange and return the right value? Or is there another better solution?

Comment: If you make it wait then you are absolutely killing the whole purpose of AJAX which is meant to be asynchronous. See my updated answer for an example of how you could write your `Parse` function so that it doesn't return any value but rather use a callback.

Comment: I am building a library which is working towards an API. So this approach is still good for that purpose? Also do you have any resources i could read about differences between sync and async?

Comment: Yes, using callbacks is the correct way to write asynchronous code. You will organize your library methods so they work with callbacks.

Comment: Do i even need to make my current function return an Object then? Couldn't i just make it into a void and depend fully on the callback?

Comment: Yes, your `Parse` method should not return anything. Let me update my answer with a TypeScript example.

Comment: Is there anyway when later calling the asynchronous function to retrieve the obj value outside the callback function? Or would all code depending on the obj variable have to live inside the callback function?

Comment: Also if i would go back to choosing a Synchronous request how would i create a timeout feature for this? Thats the reason i switched to async in the first place. Whats the pros / cons?

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a callback to the function:

```
static Parse(url: string, onSuccess: Function): Object{
  Asserts.isUrl(url, 'URL is invalid');

  var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
          if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {
              var obj = new Object();
              obj = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
              onSuccess(obj)
           }
      }
  };

  xmlHttp.open('GET', url, true);
  xmlHttp.timeout = 2000;
  xmlHttp.ontimeout = function () {
    xmlHttp.abort();
    throw new Error("Request Timed Out.");
  };
  xmlHttp.send();

}
```

and call the function with your callback parameter.